# Localization without route prefix doesn't work

Tags: laravel, localization, laravel-5.1

I'm using the Laravel docs to implement localization (without the prefix in the url).

Basically I want two links "EN" and "NL". Depending on which link I click, the locale should be changed to that specific language.

I use this links:

```
<a href="/language/benl">NL</a>
<a href="/language/en">EN</a>
```

This route:

```
Route::get('language/{locale}', 'HomeController@setLang');
```

And this is my `HomeController`:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{

    public function setLang($locale){
        App::setLocale($locale);
        return back();
    }
}
```

I set my files in `resources/lang` the way it's explained in the docs.
But, the output ( `{{ trans('messages.welcome') }}` ) isn't translated.

What am I doing wrong? :)

UPDATE

```
<a href="/auth/register">{{ trans('header.register') }}</a>
```

Routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['language']], function () {
    //
    Route::get('language/{locale}', 'HomeController@setLang');

});
```

Lang file:

```
return [
    'register' => 'REGISTREER',
];
```

My Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'language' => \App\Http\Middleware\Language::class,
    ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to prefix the urls, you could use the `session` in conjunction with a `middleware`.

All you need is a `controller` and a [`middleware`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#defining-middleware).

#### App\Http\Controllers\HomeController method:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function setLang($locale)
    {
        // 1. store selected locale
        Session::put('my_project.locale', $locale);

        return back();
    }
}
```

#### App\Http\LocaleMiddleware method:

```
class LocaleMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $default = config('app.locale');

        // 2. retrieve selected locale if exist (otherwise return the default)
        $locale = Session::get('my_project.locale', $default);

        // 3. set the locale
        App::setLocale($locale);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

> Do not forget to [register the middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#registering-middleware) **globally**.

Comment: It's a dummy name for the `key`, it can be anything.

Comment: Could you provide some more information with your solution? I assume that I need to add a middleware group on my /language/{locale} route?

Comment: I did everything you suggested. I die and dumped $locale before it's passed to `App::setLocale($locale);` and it returns the right language, still nothing changes.. :/

Comment: You did not set the files properly in the `resources/lang` then :\

Comment: Could you add these files to your question?

Comment: As I said above, you should register the `middleware` **globally**. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#registering-middleware